# Tumblr sidebar overlapping the main column

Tags: css, tumblr, sidebar, overlap, overlapping

I have a very specific issue with my sidebar in a tumblr blog. I have put it in to encompass all the navigation and fixed it on the left, but it overlaps the main column:

I cannot find a way of making the main body separate and starting to the right of the sidebar. I am clearly missing something. (Well, I think I need to encompass and define the position of the posts, but I can't see where or what.)

Thank you,

Ana

Answer (score 0):

It's the `position: fixed` on the sidebar that is giving you grief. If you must have that, you could set a left margin on the `#main` section:

```
#main {margin-left: 200px;}
```

It leaves a very narrow content area, though, so I would consider widening the layout a bit.

I'm not a fan of `margin: 0 auto;` on the `body` element. Preferably, place everthing in a centered wrapper.

If you want the content to wrap around the sidebar, then remove `position: fixed` from the sidebar, remove the margin I showed above, and also remove `overflow: hidden` from here (line 265f.):

```
article > div {
    padding: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

That will mean that the sidebar will scroll with the content, though, and not be visible all the time.

Comment: Thank you very much, I've widened the whole thing and it seems satisfied!